# Link Checkbox Checks using 'this' without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of new to javascript. I want to be able to control checkboxes from other checkboxes. My question is:

Does javascript have some sort of 'this' that I can use to send the clicked element to the function without having to "get" it in the function?(please see code below)

This code works:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" onclick="toggleCheckBox('checkBox1', 'checkBox2')">Check Box 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2">Check Box 2</input>

function toggleCheckBox(checkBox1, checkBox2) {
    var cb1 = document.getElementById(checkBox1);
    var cb2 = document.getElementById(checkBox2);

    if (cb1.checked == true) {
        cb2.checked = true;
    } else {
        cb2.checked = false;
    };
};
```

Does something like this exist?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this, 'checkBox2')">Check Box 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2">Check Box 2</input>

function toggleCheckBox(checkBox1, checkBox2) {
    var cb2 = document.getElementById(checkBox2);

    if (checkBox1.checked == true) {
        cb2.checked = true;
    } else {
        cb2.checked = false;
    };
};
```

Comment: ofc exist. You can use function as jquery function and operate with this as content of element where you clicked.

Comment: Yes, this exists. Your second code snippet works perfectly.

Comment: Dumbfounded, I copied and pasted my code from this post to my .js file(had already modified it further). I'm not sure what I had wrong, but it works. @JBDouble05

Comment: On a side note: I would recommend binding to the change event as opposed to click. It’s less fragile and will allow you to tab and press the space bar to toggle the check, which helps accessibility.

Comment: Good tip. Although at least in Firefox it doesn't make a difference, or doesn't seem to at least. @Nate

Comment: @CarlBrubaker I'll put it in an answer for future reference.

Comment: @CarlBrubaker Can you please upvote me?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker I also don't know how various accessibility programs work (such as software that helps blind people navigate websites). One thing is for certain though, the `change` event is really what you care about. You don't care if someone `click`s a check box. That's irrelevant. You care if the value of the checkbox `change`s. Clicking the checkbox is just one of many ways to change the value. Another way is with a label that has a `for` attribute, which this `click` event would not cover. What you have here is a domino effect. Watch the event you actually care about.

Comment: Thanks @Nate   Can you look at my next problem? [parent/child checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011944/link-checkboxes-with-parent-child-relationship-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have works:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this, 'checkBox2')">Check Box 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2">Check Box 2</input>

function toggleCheckBox(checkBox1, checkBox2) {
    var cb2 = document.getElementById(checkBox2);

    if (checkBox1.checked == true) {
        cb2.checked = true;
    } else {
        cb2.checked = false;
    };
};
```

The `this` object is used when your function is used by multiple objects, and the function acts only upon the single one.

Answer (score 2):

the onclick itself sends your handler function the event. In the event, you can check its target:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" onclick="toggleCheckBox">Check Box 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2" onclick="toggleCheckBox">Check Box 2</input>

function toggleCheckBox(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

This should get you started; you can then check e.target to see if it is checkBox1 or checkBox2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you will need jQuery in future. You can use this version.

```
$.fn.toggleCheckBox = function(e) {
    const nextCheckbox =$(this).data('checkbox-click');
    alert(nextCheckbox);
    $('#'+nextCheckbox).prop('checked', true);
};

$('input[data-checkbox-click]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleCheckBox();
});
```

All you need is add this data attribute

```
data-checkbox-click="checkBox2"
```

where you want to listen click and then set up your related #ID as value.

http://jsfiddle.net/k80rfe7z/9/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<script>
    function toggleCheckBox(checkBox1) {
        checkBox1.nextElementSibling.checked=checkBox1.checked;
    };
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this)">Check Box 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2">Check Box 2</input>
```

[check it live](http://jsfiddle.net/sqyo51mx/13/)

---

**But**, Your answer:

somewhat "yes"! name of this capability is `propagation` or `bubbling`.

this answer supports `Two Way` effect:

```
<div onclick="toggleCheckBox(event)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1">Check Box 1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2">Check Box 2</input>
</div>

<script>
    function toggleCheckBox(ev) {
        var t=(window.event||ev).target;
        if(t.tagName.toLowerCase()=="input"){ 
           (t.nextElementSibling||t.previousElementSibling).checked=t.checked;
        };
    };
</script>
```

**Tip:** it is better to put your input's label similar this (in this case above code must change base on that):

```
<label><input type='checkbox'/> CheckBox1</label>
```

Comment: My checkboxes will not be siblings in the way I will try to use them.