# Link Checkboxes with Parent/Child Relationship without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to explain it. Hopefully my code is self-evident. I am fairly new to javascript.

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this)">Check Box 1</input>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox2">Check Box 2</input>
  </div>
</div>

function toggleCheckBox(checkBox1) {
    // I've also tried 'checkBox1.parent' and 'checkBox1.parentElement'
    var cb2 = checkBox1.parentNode.getElementByTagName('div').getElementByTagName('input');

    if (checkBox1.checked == true) {
        cb2.checked = true;
    } else {
        cb2.checked = false;
    };
};
```

I keep getting  `checkBox1.parent` is undefined.

Edit:

final desired out come:

```
<div id="a">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this)">Check Box 1</input>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">Check Box 2</input>
    <input type="checkbox">Check Box 3</input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this)">Check Box 1</input>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">Check Box 2</input>
    <input type="checkbox">Check Box 3</input>
  </div>
</div>
```

and so on.

**Edit: Parent Indeterminate**

I got the parent to go to `indeterminate`, but it won't leave unless you click it.

```
/* clicked child checkbox */
    var parentId = clickedBox.dataset.parent;
    var checkedTrue = false;
    var checkedFalse = false;
    var checkState = clickedBox.checked;
    Array.prototype.slice.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(checkbox) {
      /* search checkboxes having same data-parent as clickedBox and is not checked */
      if (parentId === checkbox.dataset.parent && !checkbox.checked) {
        checkedFalse = true;
        checkState = false;
        return false;
      } else if (parentId === checkbox.dataset.parent && checkbox.checked) {
        checkedTrue = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    /* search parent checkbox of clickedBox */
    Array.prototype.slice.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(parentBox) {
      if (parentBox.id === parentId) {
        if (checkedTrue === true && checkedFalse === true) {
          parentBox.indeterminate = true;
          return false;
        } else {
          parentBox.checked = checkState;
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: You have no reference to the dom element. `const checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkBox1');` You can get the reference to the parent (eg. the `div`) of this element w/ `checkbox1.parentElement`

Comment: Is there a way to get the element to 'send itself' to the function without having to "get" it again? @bradcush

Comment: If you assign the reference of your dom element to the `checkbox1` variable for example, outside of your function before you declare it, you will have access to it inside of the function declaration as well.

Comment: Didn't I do that with "toggleCheckBox(this)" ? @bradcush

Comment: Yes you did, I missed that when I originally took a look. I would keep as much JS out of your HTML as possible though.

Comment: So why doesn’t it work?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: checkBox1.parentNode.getElementByTagName is not a function` is the error when your code is run. If you have any more questions you can start a chat, glad to help.

Comment: I opened a chat @bradcush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-case use of HTML5 `data-*` is not an constraint, this solution works with most of updated browsers including IE 11. Here, I am using `data-parent` attribute(having value same as `id` of parent) to link checkbox with its parent checkbox. Value `-1` for `data-parent` denotes that there is no parent for the given checkbox.

```js
let allCheckboxes;
/* checkbox click handler */
let toggleCheck = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var clicked = this;
  /* clicked ones is the parent */
  if ('-1' === clicked.dataset.parent) {
    /* search child checkboxes having data-parent=id of clicked ones */
    Array.prototype.slice.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
      if (c.dataset.parent === clicked.id) {
        /* set checked state same as clicked ones */
        c.checked = clicked.checked;
      }
    });
  } else {
    /* clicked ones is child checkbox */
    var parentId = clicked.dataset.parent;
    var checkState = clicked.checked;
    Array.prototype.slice.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
      /* search checkboxes having data-parent same as clicked ones and is not checked */
      if (parentId === c.dataset.parent && !c.checked) {
        checkState = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
    /* search parent checkbox of clicked ones */
    Array.prototype.slice.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
      if (c.id === parentId) {
        c.checked = checkState;
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
};
/* wait till DOM renderes and available to bind event listneres */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* fetch all checkboxes having attributes data-parent and id */
  allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][data-parent][id]');
  /* iterate over all checkboxed to bind click listeners */
  Array.prototype.slice.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
    c.addEventListener('click', toggleCheck);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="-1" id="c1"/>Check Box 1</label>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c1" id="c2">Check Box 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c1" id="c3">Check Box 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="-1" id="c4">Check Box 1</label>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c4" id="c5">Check Box 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c4" id="c6">Check Box 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. `</input>` is invalid tag.

**Edited:** Regarding `checkState` since as of now I have not provided any `intermediate` state for parent checkbox, so what I did is took the checked state of `clicked` child checkbox, if its checked then searched from the list of other remaining child checkboxes having same parent id. When encountered anymore child checkboxes which is not checked then I simply mark parent checkbox as `unchecked`.

**With intermediate**: Well, its not that fancy but does the trick.

```js
let allCheckboxes;
let repeat = Array.prototype.slice;
let applyState = function(checkbox, state) {
  let classes = checkbox.parentNode.classList;
  if (!state || !checkbox.checked) {
    classes.remove("checked");
    classes.remove("intermediate");
    checkbox.dataset.state = 0;
  }
  if (1 === state || checkbox.checked) {
    classes.add("checked");
    checkbox.dataset.state = 1;
  }
  if (2 === state) {
    classes.remove("checked");
    classes.add("intermediate");
    checkbox.dataset.state = 2;
  }
}
/* checkbox click handler */
let toggleCheck = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var clicked = this;
  applyState(clicked);
  /* clicked ones is the parent */
  if ('-1' === clicked.dataset.parent) {
    /* search child checkboxes having data-parent=id of clicked ones */
    repeat.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
      if (c.dataset.parent === clicked.id) {
        /* set checked state same as clicked ones */
        c.checked = clicked.checked;
        applyState(c);
      }
    });
  } else {
    /* clicked ones is child checkbox */
    var parentId = clicked.dataset.parent;
    var check = 0,
      uncheck = 0;
    repeat.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
      /* search checkboxes having data-parent same as clicked ones */
      if (parentId === c.dataset.parent) {
        if (c.checked) {
          check++;
        } else {
          uncheck++;
        }
      }
    });
    /* search parent checkbox of clicked ones */
    repeat.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
      if (c.id === parentId) {
        var state = 1;
        if (0 === check) {
          state = 0;
          c.checked = false;
        } else if (0 < uncheck) {
          state = 2;
        }
        applyState(c, state);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
};
/* wait till DOM renderes and available to bind event listneres */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* fetch all checkboxes having attributes data-parent and id */
  allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][data-parent][id]');
  /* iterate over all checkboxed to bind click listeners */
  repeat.call(allCheckboxes).forEach(function(c) {
    c.addEventListener('click', toggleCheck);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

label>input {
  display: none;
}

label:before {
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "";
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

label.checked:before,
label.intermediate:before {
  color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}

label.checked:before {
  content: "\2713";
  padding: 0px 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

label.intermediate:before {
  content: "\2012";
  padding: 0px 4px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="-1" id="c1"/>Check Box 1</label>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c1" id="c2">Check Box 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c1" id="c3">Check Box 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="-1" id="c4">Check Box 1</label>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c4" id="c5">Check Box 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-parent="c4" id="c6">Check Box 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, since I am newer(ish) to JavaScript, I had a lot of terms to look up from your code to figure out how it all works together. Since Microsoft has abandoned IE, I don't think I concerned about that. But I was curious about the `data-*`, since it looks like you used it too. I couldn't find an answer that made sense. Could you elaborate more on it, it give me a link that explains it well?

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding the logic on the checkState and how it effects the parent checkbox. I really want to understand this, but I need a few more details. @Arvind

Comment: Yes, I thought that is what was going on. I think what really confuses me is: checkState = clicked, then checkState = false. I can’t figure out where the parent becomes !.checked. Oh. I just got it. I thought the first return false ended the function, but it still passes to the final if. I thought it false-ing the clicker box. Now maybe I can figure out my indeterminate for the parent box. Thanks.

Comment: I got close, but can't quite figure it out the `indeterminate`. @Arvind Added my attempt above.

Comment: Interesting. I managed to get mine to work by adding `parentBox.indeterminate = false;` to my else statement. I was curious how you would handle it. Thanks again. I learned so much. Hope your health gets better. @Arvind

Comment: Bonus points for knowing without me telling you that I would want to change the style of my checkboxes. @Arvind

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do. One thing to note, this solution does not support IE11 or below, as it uses `closest()` to find parent nodes by a selector.

https://caniuse.com/#search=closest

(You may have to click the GIF to get it to play.)

[image: Example]

```
<div data-checkbox-group>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-master-checkbox /> Master</label>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 1</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 2</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 3</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 4</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 5</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div data-checkbox-group>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-master-checkbox /> Master</label>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 1</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 2</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 3</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 4</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 5</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div data-checkbox-group>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-master-checkbox /> Master</label>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 1</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 2</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 3</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 4</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check Box 5</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<script>
  var toggleChecks = function() {
    var isMaster = this.hasAttribute('data-master-checkbox')
    var group = this.closest('[data-checkbox-group]')
    var boxes = group.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not([data-master-checkbox])')
    var master = isMaster ? this : group.querySelector('input[type=checkbox][data-master-checkbox]')

    if (isMaster) {
      // Set all children to the value of the parent
      for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].checked = this.checked
      }
    } else {
      // Toggle all children to the state of the master
      var checkedCount = 0
      for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if(boxes[i].checked) { checkedCount += 1 }
      }

      master.checked = checkedCount == boxes.length
      master.indeterminate = !master.checked && !checkedCount == 0
    }
  }

  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-checkbox-group] input[type=checkbox]')
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].addEventListener('change', toggleChecks)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, my end goal is to have multiple divs like above on the same page. I’m trying to get one function that will handle them all.

Comment: Okay, and where the Check Box 2 is, can there be multiple? Like 1 parent that controls 5 children, for example? @CarlBrubaker

Comment: Thanks Nate. I appreciate the effort you put in, but through my research I've found that `closest()` apparently doesn't work with Edge either. Arvind has the better answer.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery has a closest method. I should take a look at what it does. It probably traverses the DOM up until it gets a hit. Now I’m curious if I could whip something up with better support. I didn’t know if you’d want to manage a ton of html ids like that. Though, if it works, then cool!